# How to initialize StringDictionary in my project settings

Tags: c#, project-settings, stringdictionary

I've added a StringDictionary to my project settings in VS2010. When I try to add members to it in my program, I get a `NullReferenceException`. When I try to initialize a value in its `Value` column in my project settings, it says my entry cannot be converted to StringDictionary. I'm sure it's looking for some XML code, but isn't there a better way to initialize the StringDictionary before compilation?

Additional info:

1. Go to Menu -> Project -> [Project Name]> Properties... -> Settings
2. Add a setting named `mySetting` of type `System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary`
3. In your code add a line `[ProjectName].Properties.Settings.Default.mySetting.Add("key","value");`
4. Run and get the exception.

Comment: show your **code** please.

Comment: Thanks! There's really not much code since it's all GUI in VS2010. I've added some steps on how to generate the error.

Comment: for value try `new System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary()` or something. This is just a guess though since I've not tried it myself but it looks like you need to initialize your dictionary and this seems like a not bad way of doing it. Or alternatively if that doesn't work try setting it via code in some kind of initialiser.

Comment: `StringDictionary` is basically only useful in C# 1.x.  There's really no need t use it at all in later versions outside of possibly some legacy apps.  Just use `Dictionary`.

Comment: Thanks. On Servy's suggestion I used a different class. `Dictionary` was not a type option that I could select so I'm now using a `Hashtable` instead. When I click on the `...` button in its `Value` column I'm not able to add anything to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using two `ArrayList` settings in place of the one `Hashtable` setting.